# Is it possible to upload to root of sub-folders with Google picker?

Tags: javascript, google-picker

We have a working google file picker but our users gets confused by having to select the folders and not being able to save in the root of the current folder they are at. Is there some option that can be used to change the behaviour of the picker so that is possible? Or maybe a different approach entirely?

This is a small snippet of the angular code that sets up the behaviour of the google picker:

```
    const pickerBuilder = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();

    view = new google.picker.DocsView()
      .setParent('root')
      .setIncludeFolders(true);
    view.setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
      .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
    picker = pickerBuilder
      .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
      .setOAuthToken(this.oauthToken.access_token)
      .addView(view)
      .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically we ended up giving our users 2 options:

- Save to root
- Save to folder

not an optimal solution but it made it possible to save in the root AND by having the save text mention folder it would give the user a hint about how the regular save feature works.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a picker for selecting the folder, and when the file is selected, create a new instance of the picker with the `DocsUploadView` and set the parent via `DocsUploadView.setParent(string)` to the one the user chose.

Just a sketch on how this may be accomplished:

###### First we create two functions two render the different pickers

```js
function createPickerFolders() {
  const view = new google.picker.DocsView()
    .setIncludeFolders(true)
    .setSelectFolderEnabled(true)
    .setMimeTypes("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

  const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .addView(view)
    .setAppId(appId)
    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
    .setCallback(pickerViewCallback)
    .build();
  picker.setVisible(true);
}

function createPickerUpload(folderId) {
  const view = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent(folderId);

  const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .addView(view)
    .setAppId(appId)
    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
    .setCallback(pickerUploadCallback)
    .build();

  picker.setVisible(true);
}
```

###### For the callback of the `DocsView` we create one that renders the `DocsUploadView` and sets it's parent to the folder selected

```js
function pickerViewCallback(data) {
  if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    const folderId = data.docs[0].id;
    createPickerUpload(folderId);
  }
}
```

In this way we achieve that the folder selected by the user, is the one to which the file is uploaded.

###### Documentation:

- [`DocsUploadView`](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference)
- [`DocsView`](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference)

Comment: Not quite what we're looking after. We want the regular picker dialog but we want to be able to click select both with a folder selected and without.

Comment: As I say this is a sketch of what it might look like. But, if you add the two views to both pickers, this should achieve exactly what you want, right?

Comment: Not quite. We want 1 picker dialog and we want the select button to NOT be greyed out when we haven't selected a folder. We've found another workaround to the problem but it isn't as elegant as what we wanted ;)

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution, could you provide it as an answer? Maybe other members of the Stack Overflow community find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to implement same functionality in my project and ended up as same warpzit explain. Google Picker doesn't has such configuration.
Here is my implementation

```
function pickerViewCallback(data) {
 if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
  const folderId = 'root';
  createPickerUpload(folderId);
 }
}
```

To save files in **My Drive** which top folder just set **id = 'root'**.
Refer Google picker code example to implement it in web. [picker sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample)